# change string into var datatype in c#

Tags: c#

I am reading data from file like this

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("newfile.txt"))
{

            string lines1;
            lines1 = r.ReadLine();
            var lines = lines1;

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
                var records = line.Split(',');
```

How can i convert string data type to var data type?

if i used this line

```
   var lines = lines1;
```

then the error accur at

```
 var records = line.Split(',');
```

Comment: Please at least tag your questions properly if not format them.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a `var` datatype.  "var", in C#, just means "let the compiler figure out the data type for me based on the context".  in this case, using:

```
var lines = lines1;
```

or:

```
string lines = lines1;
```

Will produce the exact same code.  The error message is not related to the usage of `var` instead of `string`.

The problem here is this:

```
lines1 = r.ReadLine();
var lines = lines1;

// ...
foreach (string line in lines)
```

You're reading a *single line* as a *single string*, then trying to do: "foreach string in my single string".  I suspect you want something more like:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("newfile.txt"))
{
    while (r.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        string line = r.ReadLine();
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
        var records = line.Split(',');
        // use records....  Note that above is the same as:
        // string[] records = line.Split(',');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "split" function returns an array.

Comment: Your response would be more appropriate as a comment.